# Common practice in handling bounce message

Tags: email

At now I mainly create a mail account separately  (with different domain name eg.noreply@example.com) and i add this mail as one return path. So the bounce message will only go to that mailbox and i parse the mail message one by one to check the failure receipent and the error code, then i convert the error code to the actual error message.

Finally, the error message and the fail receipent's mail  are post to my system and let my system user check the bounce information.

Is it a common practice? Since i am worry about the mail other from bounce message have sent to my mail box, that would be a disaster if i parse them without filter them out, but how can i filter out between bounce message and normal mail?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: If you're talking about sending out mass emails, a lot of people use a paid provider to do this kind of thing for them.

Comment: Thanks.Without paying what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that the mail you are filtering is truly a bounce back then include some sort of identifying information in the email that you can verify before you notify users. This could be something like a reference number. With this reference number you can match it up with other information you already have, like time sent and to whom, to further verify the bounced email.

Comment: The `Message-ID` header might be of use here.